# Validate dates in XML Document before writing to database

Tags: xml, perl, xsd

I'm currently getting user input from a very large form as an XML document. I'd like to validate this XML document against a schema before any database related operations. The problem is that users input dates according to their own preferences (US standard, ISO standard, etc.) and the database expects dates to be ISO standard. Is there anyway I can validate this XML document and change the dates to ISO format before adding it to the database? I'm using Perl for the back-end, any libraries that can help me do the same?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For date conversion

[HTTP::Date](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-5.837/lib/HTTP/Date.pm)

For dealing with xmls in general

[Perl-XML](http://perl-xml.sourceforge.net/)

PM for processing XLST (you guessed it)

[XML::XLST](http://search.cpan.org/~jstowe/XML-XSLT-0.48/lib/XML/XSLT.pm)

Comment: That certainly would be useful, but I would prefer having the validating in the schema itself. That way, other applications, using the same schema would work as well. Is there a way to put the validation in the schema for 'date' elements? And validate against that schema to correct date formats which aren't accepted by the database?

Comment: @Gaurav, that's a tricky one... the only time I've ever used Perl for XML parsing/checking I used this other module now in post

Comment: @Gaurav, as for your more recent (and more demanding) clarification on your question, I don't believe I can help you on that.

Comment: @William Thanks for that link! Sorry to keep pushing on, but I think there might be a way to have XSLT transforms to change the date within the XML document to the correct formats? Is there no library for that? Thanks a lot mate! :)

Comment: @Gaurav ahhh, this one perhaps?

Comment: That really helps. I'll try to code a little prototype to see if it works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There is [Data::Validate::XSD](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Data%3a%3aValidate%3a%3aXSD) with which I do not have any experience.

In the past, I did use [XML::LibXML::Schema](http://search.cpan.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aSchema).

I would traverse the document, converting all dates using [DateTime::Format::XSD](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aXSD) (in conjunction with [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DateTime)) and then attempt to validate.

Comment: DateTime::Format::XSD is definitely useful, but then again, it only parses ISO formats to a particular ISO format. It would have troubles with Aus standard (dd/mm/yyyy) or US standard (mm/dd/yyyy) formats. Ideally, I'd like to have an XSL transform before the validation to change these dates to the right format - then just validate the document and then write to the DB

Answer (score 0):

You can have a little schema to validate your special date with a regexp, then an xslt to transform your date to other format, then a schema to validate all your xml document.